# How to used datepicker dialogdragment different edittext

Tags: java, android

I have DatepickerFragment which extends from DialogFragment. In my main fragment there are two edittext.The first one is for starting date and the second is for finising date. These are for some user operations.User clicks first edittext choose date and the other one is same way But i confused about how to handle edittexts on DatepickerFragment.What is best way for it ?

```
    etOverFlowingStaringDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
            DatePickerFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            datePickerFragment.show(fragmentManager, "datepicker");
        }
    });
```

DatepickerFragment.java

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        populateSetDate(year, monthOfYear+1, dayOfMonth);
    }

    private void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

       String datetime = dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year ;

        //EditText edtext = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.overflow_starting_date);
        // The edittext is changable it is not a good way to define in here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create my custom `DatePickerFragment`s in a separate class and then use the Listener model to implement what you are trying to achieve. Essentially:

In your DatePickerFragment, define an interface -

```
public interface OnDateChosenListener {
    void onDateChosen(int year, int month, int day);
}
```

Then, define a private variable within your DatePickerFragment class for that interface -

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    private OnDateChosenListener mOnDateChosenListener = null;

    ...
```

Add a function to set an OnDateChosenListener -

```
public void setOnDateChosenListener(OnDateChosenListener listener) {
    mOnDateChosenListener = listener;
}
```

Final thing for the DatePickerFragment class, pass along event and values to the listener if it exists -

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    if (mOnDateChosenListener != null) {
        mOnDateChosenListener.onDateChosen(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }
}
```

Lastly, MOST IMPORTANT. Remember to add a listener wherever you use the new DatePickerFragment, in your case, an Activity -

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
DatePickerFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
datePickerFragment.addOnDateChosenListener(new OnDateChosenListener() {
    public void onDateChosen(int year, int month, int day) {
        // use values to change EditText value
    }
}
datePickerFragment.show(fragmentManager, "datepicker");
```

The Listener model is a good practice and is widely used in the Android framework.

Comment: where did you define addOnDateChosenListener ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question very well, but are you trying to get the date on the `EditText` once the user selects it? If that's the case...

Create an interface that will receive your date in your activity/fragment:

```
interface DateReceiver {
    void update(int year, int month, int day); 
}
```

Implement your activity/fragment, then implement the method:

```
@Override
public void update(int year, int month, int day) {
     String date = //format your date here;
     this.editText.setText(date);
}
```

If you add the `onClickListener` to your editText...:

```
etOverFlowingStaringDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        fragment.setReceiver(MainActivity.this); //assuming your activity is called MainActivity.this. 'this' alone won't work.
        fragment.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "datePicker"); //do getActivity().getFragmentManager in a Fragment
    }
});
```

As you may have noticed, I wrote `fragment.setReceiver(MainActivity.this)`. This method is created and defined below.

Then, you should coninue by implementing your `DatePickerFragment` as follows:

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    private DateReceiver receiver;
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int year = TransactionUtils.getFragment().mYearChosen;
        int month = TransactionUtils.getFragment().mMonthChosen;
        int day = TransactionUtils.getFragment().mDayChosen;

        //If you want the minimum date to be today...
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
        return datePickerDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        updateDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }

    public void setReceiver(DateReceiver receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    private void updateDate(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        if (receiver != null) //avoiding NullPointerExceptions :D
              receiver.update(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }
}
```

Calling update in `private void updateDate(int,int,int)` will change the date of your editText.